# mostrar gráficamente QR recibido desde API

Tags: php, api, qrcode

este es mi primera publicación, tengo un problema con un QR, lo que pasa es lo siguiente recibo datos de una API el cual me hace el envío de un QR pero este no se ve de forma gráfica si no se ve de la siguiente manera: `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`

Lo que no sé es como codificar toda esta cadena para que se vea de forma gráfica sin perder la información que contiene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se trata de eso. Revise tu codigo, enrealidad es una fotografia PNG codificada como BASE 64, para esto debes utilizar alguna libreria en el proyecto que estas utilizando, o alguna funcion como "base64_decode"  con esto convertiras tu imagen codificada, en un binario que podras desplegar, guardar, mostrar, etc.

Espero te sea de utilidad

Probe con este conversor online. Saludos

[Enlace a conversor online BASE64 a Imagen](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter)

Comment: [Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) +1 y tienes razón al indicar que el "texto" es en realidad una imagen en base64. Usando https://www.freeformatter.com/base64-encoder.html se puede descargar el código QR.

Comment: que bueno que te sirvió! saludos!!! llevo bastante consumiendo ayuda de la plataforma, también quiero aportar un granito de arena en lo que se pueda.

Comment: Eso está muy bien, Osvaldo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar cualquiera de las herramientas disponibles en internet para graficar el texto en un código QR:

- https://github.com/endroid/qr-code
- https://kazuhikoarase.github.io/qrcode-generator/js/demo/

Te recomiendo revisar si efectivamente este texto es un texto válido (ya que,al usar, por ejemplo https://www.qr-code-generator.com/) no lo pudo graficar.

Comment: Exacto, también probé con codificadores en linea unos crean el qr gráficamente pero al escanear no me devuelve la información correcta encriptada en esta cadena que me devuelve la API

Comment: @MegaPattern entonces es probable que la información a graficar en un código QR no sea válida *(está incompleta o excede la cantidad de caracteres...)*. Te recomiendo consultar con quien está proporcionando la API para indicarle esta situación.